# Get row data from cursor - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code -

```
cursor get_supllies IS
select t_supplies.*, rowid
from t_supplies;
```

When I am in the loop I need to insert this row  to a different table. I must keep the rowid and I cannot remove it from the cursor.

```
for i in  get_supplies loop


insert into t_suppliers_errors
values i; 

end loop;
```

Is there away to get only t_suppliers row data from cursor?

Comment: what is the problem in mentioning the columns explicitly while inserting ?

Comment: I also use it for outside procedure

Comment: Could you provide the complete code and mention the use case in the question itself ? could be other ways if we see the use cases. I didn't get the part of usage outside procedure.

Comment: Please make sure the code is working before you asking => get_supllies and get_supplies.

Answer (score 0):

Assuiming that
`t_supplies` has the following columns:

```
(col_1,col_2,col_3)
```

and

`t_suppliers_errors` has the following columns:

```
(ecol_1,ecol_2,ecol_3)
```

The code would be like the following:

```
for i in  get_supplies loop


insert into t_suppliers_errors(ecol_1,ecol_2,ecol_3)
values (i.col_1,i.col_2,i.col_3); 

end loop;
```